# Can I do the Hoashanas service if praying alone?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, sukkot, tzibur-community, hoshana-rabbah

If one is not able to make it to a minyan one day during sukkos, can he still say or do any of the day's Hoshanas services? Would it be different on Hoshanah Rabbah because of the additions?

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to?

Answer (score 4):

I can't see any reason why lack of a minyan invalidates regular hoshanot.

The Ben Ish Chai (last subsection in first year parshat Haazinu) says that the main requirement according to the kabbalists is to encircle the tevah /bimah  one on each day of chol hamoed an 7 on hoshaanah rabbah (even though no Sefer Torah is present). He mentions that people who would do it around a chair at home (who couldn't get to synagogue) are not fulfilling the true essence of the custom, "eino klum." (Yet, he doesn't say that its bad either. He adds that an infirmed person, who has no option of getting to a synagogue with a bimah doesn't lose by putting a Tanach on a chair and doing it at home, and quotes the verse "G-d doesn't withhold good from those that walk in his ways innocently" – [Tehilim 84:12](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2684.htm#12)).

On hoshanah rabbah the custom of the Sfardim is to add some excerpts from selichot, some of which are in Aramaic ("rachamana idkar lan..."), which at least during the selichot the custom is not to say alone (see Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 128:9). Perhaps that would also require a minyan, however, Rav Mordechai Eliyahu ztzl in his notes there brings the Kaf haChaim 591:26, who is lenient on the Aramaic passages.
Ashkenazim however do not seem to say those passages at all during the hoshanah rabbah additions.
The Yemenite and Spanish and Portuguese custom is to say the 13 middot of rachamim on hoshanah rabbah, which are not to be said without a minyan in the form of prayer (see previously quoted Kitzur), but according to some authorities can be said with the normal tune of reading (see Ben Ish Chai Ki Tissah 9 first year).

Comment: Maran harav ovadia sheyihye writes that one can even use a humash.