# Holding the lulav and esrog while saying hoshanos at home

Tags: halacha, sukkot, tzibur-community, hoshanos

When one davens at home b’yechidus, assuming he still [says the hoshanos prayers every day, including hoshanah rabbah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31331/can-i-do-the-hoashanas-service-if-praying-alone), would he hold the lulav and esrog while saying them?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be holding them and even walk around a chumash placed on a chair or table(Ben Ish Chai parashat Ha'azinu 15; see footnote 2 in link 1 below).

It's not absolutely required, but an option available in order to maintain tradition and add merit, in my opinion; and is a worthy practice since it isn't too difficult(see link 2).

Links in hebrew:

1)https://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/90399

2)http://chabad.org.il/Questions/Index.asp?SubjectID=5&QuestionID=22349&CategoryID=68

Comment: In the Dirshu Mishna Berurah they quote this from the Ben Ish Chai and others and also bring others who disagree.

Comment: quote sources as soon as you find them

Comment: @user15464 as I said it's quoted in the Dirshu Mishna Berurah.  I don't have it on me now but it's in the siman on hoshanos.