# Hoshanot without a Minyan - removing the Torah from the Aron Hakodesh

Tags: halacha, sukkot, ark-aron-kodesh, hoshanos

There are nine men at Shacharit on Hol HaMoed Sukkot, one short of a minyan. Hoshanot can be recited without a minyan. Should the Torah be removed from the Aron when reciting Hoshanot with only nine men present?

Comment: possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31331/759